# Is it safe to do something like foo(x, &x)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Note, I would not write code like this. I'm just curious, and it would help me writing a better answer for another question. But let's say that we have this function:

```
void foo(int a, int *b)
{
    *b  = 2*a;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int x=42;
foo(x, &x);
```

Apart from the fact that it is a very strong code smell, can this cause any real problems? Is it UB or does it violate any rules in the C standard?

Comment: It's fine. The current value of `x` at the time of the call is *copied*. The function argument `a` contains that copied value.

Comment: @4386427 I had no reason to assume it would be illegal. Simply just wanted to make it 100% sure. After all, C can be a bit strange from time to time. :)

Comment: @4386427 Because almost nothing in C is legal.

Comment: @Boann: Under a sufficiently pedantic reading of the Standard, almost nothing would be allowed in "strictly conforming" programs.  On the other hand, essentially nothing would be forbidden fore programs that seek merely to be "conforming".

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int x=42;
foo(x, &x);
```

is a well-formed code. The order of the evaluation of arguments is not important in this case.

In fact the function call is equivalent to

```
foo( 42, &x);
```

because the first argument is passed by value.

Comment: Note that foo(x, &x) is valid even if x value can't be determined at compile time like in the above example; you can always determine the value of a variable and its address regardless the order of evaluation

Comment: To be pedantic: The second argument is also passed by value. The pointer argument is passed as copy to the pointer parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The code is OK, but to dig a bit deeper between the lines to see what special case situations exist, which ones that are fine and which ones that could potentially cause problems:

- The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified and unsequenced, but it does not matter in this specific case.
- Function arguments are evaluated before passed to a function, then there is a sequence point after the evaluation. Meaning that all calculations and side effects in the arguments occur before the function is called (but in an unspecified order in relation to each other).

  So even (artificial crap) code such as this is actually well-defined:

  ```
    void foo(int a, int *b)
    {
       printf("%d\n", a); // prints 42
      *b = 2**b;          // gives 43 * 43 = 86
    }
    ...
    int x=42;
    foo(x++, &x);
  ```

  The `x++` vs `&x` is fine since `&x` is not a value computation of the object. And thanks to the sequence points, the `x++` occurs before the calculation inside the function, so that part is also well-defined.
- The parameter `a` inside the function is of course a local copy of caller-side `x`, so the function can do what it pleases with that one.
- Had it been two pointers pointing at the same object, then they would "overlap" and that's undefined behavior in some cases, depending on what the function does. For example `memcpy(&x, &x, sizeof x);` is undefined behavior.
- There is a sequence point at each `;` and also at the end of the function.
- For variables declared at file scope, the function must assume that pointer parameters modifying the pointed-at value might modify the file scope variable. So in case of this code:

  ```
    void foo(int a, int *b)
    {
      extern int x;
      x = 2*a;
      printf("%d\n", *b);
    }
  ```

  the compiler must fetch the value of `*b` after the assignment to `x`, because it can't assume that `b` doesn't point at `x` - the pointer could be an *alias* of `&x`. And here's where the various rules of pointer aliasing comes in.
- Similarly, two pointer parameters of the same type might point at the same object in the caller code and the compiler isn't allowed to assume that they don't, unless we manually add a `restrict` qualifier to them.

Comment: @Bob__ Nah, I'm assuming that the reader is either a C nerd familiar with the "maximal munch rule", or that they are a normal person who finds the code abhorrent or confusing. In case of the latter, I was hopefully successful in scaring them away from writing similar code in real applications :)

Comment: Fair enough ;).

Comment: Precise and well documented. In `void foo(int a, int *b)` can we assume that `b` cannot be the address of `a` upon entering the function?

Comment: @chqrlie I don't see how it could be? Since `a` has local scope.

Comment: @Lundin: of course neither do I, but I wonder if compilers take advantage of this constraint.

Comment: @chqrlie They absolutely do, since `a` is a very likely candidate for a CPU register without any address at all.

Comment: Indeed they do, and are quite clever to determine if the address of `a` may have been used to modify it: https://godbolt.org/z/eGnW68

Answer (score 1):

The question is already [well answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63775258/5872193), but the above would work even without being in a separate function due to evaluation order.

Even the following code would work fine.

```c
void foo(int *a, int *b) {
  *b = 2*(*a);
}

int x = 42;
foo(&x, &x);
```

and `x` would contain `84` after it executes. The right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated before the left-hand side (that's why we can do `x = x+1;` and drive mathematicians crazy :) )

Comment: The C standard does not say the right-hand sign of an assignment is evaluated before the left-hand side. C 2018 6.5.16 3 says this explicitly: “… The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.” It does say “… The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands…,” but this leaves the update unsequenced relative to any other side effects and leaves all other side effects unsequenced relative to each other and to the value computations.

Comment: Maybe you could add a example with `restrict` to show when it is not valid to call `foo(&x,&x)`?

Comment: "The right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated before the left-hand side (that's why we can do x = x+1; and drive mathematicians crazy :) )" Rather, we don't know which side that is evaluated first, for the purpose of driving programmers crazy. Latter versions of C++ made this well-defined, but it is poorly defined in C and pre C++17. Gotta keep them language lawyers employed and all.

Comment: @Lundin: Assuming `int *foo(), *bar();`, does C++17 define the order of `foo()` and `bar()` in `*foo() = *bar();`? I don't think it is defined in C, what would it be in C++17?

Comment: @chqrlie C++17 is super clear: (8.5.18) "In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand is sequenced before the left operand." C++14 and C++11 were far more fuzzy regarding the last part and no C version has any of it as well-defined.

Comment: @Lundin: *The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.* this would make one-pass code generation such as TinyCC's more difficult to perform.

Comment: @chqrlie The strong trend in C++ since 2011 is to move away from efficient and hardware-related programming in favour for meta programming.

Comment: @Lundin: When using a non-compound assignment operator, on an expression like `foo[i++]`, what term does the C++ Standard use to describe what is done with the expression to the left side of the assignment operator?  It *isn't* evaluated, so I don't think saying that the left-hand side is "evaluated" after the evaluation of the right hand side specifies the sequencing of whatever is done with the left hand side.

Comment: @supercat Evaluation is synonymous to execution order in terms of standard gibberish. Though if you have multiple side effects on the same variable at the left-hand side of a simple assignment expression, sequencing is probably the least of your problems...

Comment: @Lundin: The left-hand side is `foo[i++]`; `i` appears once.  Although the sub-expression `i++` would be evaluated, the containing sub-expression `foo[i++]` would not.  If I were in charge of the Standard, I would say that the expression `foo[i++]` is *resolved*, and then either explicitly say that the left-hand side is *resolved* after the right-hand side is *evaluated*, or else say that while *evaluation* of the left-hand side occurs after that of the right, *resolution* does not.  When using assignment operators with scalar types, requiring that the RHS be evaluated before...

Comment: ...the LHS is resolved can often necessitate needlessly-inefficient code when processing something like `*someFunction() = globalObject;`, since it would be necessary to save across the function call a copy of whatever `globalObject` held before it.  When using custom operators, it makes sense to offer stronger ordering guarantees than when using conventional function calls, but for simple scalar assignments I think it imposes needless obstacles to efficient code generation.